# list phone numbers by date added, other attributes

Tags: contacts

Is there a way to list phone numbers and contacts by date added, perhaps even location they were added in like if you travel alot and meet people along the way? Seems like a fairly simple feature in the age of relational databases

I'm willing to consider third party apps that do this too

Comment: I am unaware of apps that do this, but you can go into your Google Dashboard, and manage your contacts there. I am unaware if the date or location is recorded, or accessible, but you can view your contact list from different backup points over time.

Comment: @MattClark the google dashboard thing was interesting, helpful for other reasons but not specifically this, thanks for the contribution!